# dpkg only UNPACKS and Doesn't INSTALL, why?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to use the `dpkg -b` to build a package . The package directory structure looks like :

```
ubuntu@ip-10-241-62-56:~/USB_RnD_DEB/BACKUP/usblinux1.1$ tree
.
├── DEBIAN
│   └── control
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── usblinux-runner.sh
    └── share
        └── usblinux
               |-->installer.sh
               |--> LOTS AND LOTS OF FILES
```

The `usblinux-runner.sh` consists of a small shell script which holds :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Installing the USB REDIRECTOR as Client !"
echo "-----------------------------------------"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo /usr/share/usblinux/./installer.sh install-client
```

Now this gets packed into the

```
ubuntu@ip-10-241-62-56:~/USB_RnD_DEB/BACKUP$ sudo dpkg -b usblinux1.1/
dpkg-deb: building package `usblinux' in `usblinux1.1.deb'.
ubuntu@ip-10-241-62-56:~/USB_RnD_DEB/BACKUP$ ls
usblinux1.1  usblinux1.1.deb
```

Now this works absolutely fine and when I install the package it just unpacks it and puts the usblinux-runner.sh in `/usr/bin` & usblinux in `/usr/bin/share`

It DOESN'T INSTALL or RUN the the usblinux-runner.sh file . I simply UNPACKS and doesn't RUN the shell script also i don't see any OUTPUT on console :

```
sudo dpkg -i usblinux1.1.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package usblinux.
(Reading database ... 82106 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack usblinux1.1.deb ...
Unpacking usblinux (1.1) ...
Setting up usblinux (1.1) ...
```

Can someone help me on finding whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal, installing a package doesn't run any of its binaries by default (otherwise imagine what fun we'd have installing `e2fsprogs` and the like!).

If you want the `usblinux-runner.sh` script to run automatically after the package is installed, you need to add a [`postinst` script](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html), which will run `usblinux-runner.sh`. There is one caveat: you can't install other packages from a maintainer script, so you'd need to remove the `apt-get` lines. But that's fine, because the correct way of declaring a dependency (your package depends on `build-essential`) is to declare it in the `Depends:` entry of the control file. Given all that, you might as well just have your `postinst` script run

```
/usr/share/usblinux/installer.sh install-client
```

You don't need `sudo` here, the maintainer scripts run as `root` anyway.

Comment: oh , i understand now , so this postinst script also gets packaged inside the .deb ? and then when the whole debian package UNPACKS itself it is ran. correct ?/

Comment: Also where should i put this postinst script ?

Comment: You'd put it in the `DEBIAN` directory, alongside `control`. Check out the requirements in the link in my answer, you'll need to check the arguments given to the `postinst` script; [this page on the wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts) might be helpful too.